# Advantages of "middle" tables in one-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd, architecture

Entities:

- Lists
- Leads

What I am trying to achieve is a scenerio where in the relationship between `lists` and `leads` the following constraint is applied: A list can have many leads, but a lead can only belong to one list.

Standard way of doing this is a simple non-identifying **one-to-many** relationship.

[image]

Another way I'm doing this is to create a hybrid **one-to-one** and a **one-to-many** relationship.

[image]

In both cases a list can contain many leads, but a lead can only exist in one list. Does anyone see any advantages or disadvantages to the second method? Any differences between the two methods? Any alternatives?

Comment: What does the second design gain you? I can't see any improvement over the first design TBH.

Comment: Your first approach is simpler, and it gets the job done. So I would go for it, unless there are additional requirements you did not describe in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few scenarios in which you would probably benefit from your second design:

One is if there is a sub-typing scenario where only certain a certain sub-type had the relationship (and the super-type doesn't) *and* the sub-type has other additional fields, besides the foreign key.

Another might be where the existence and value of the foreign key needs to be controlled for security reasons at a different level of granularity than the rest of the entity containing the foreign key.  Most DBMSs can handle security per table.  Most don't handle security per column.

Comment: Another good reason to go with method two is if I decided to make the lists_list_id FK optional. By moving the relationship to a pivot table, then I avoid several millions of records of potential null values in that column in the lead entity.

Comment: @SephVelut - Avoiding nulls is only important if you have a performance or space problem and your foreign key is populated only a small fraction of the time.  A lot of people like to avoid sparse table, but extending that notion to an optional column is overkill.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I prefer the latter approach. Mind you multiple tables is not a bad thing. Relational Databases are at their best when broken into discrete units.

Comment: I would also add that it creates a layer where you can separate your concerns. Say I had boolean type columns inside `lead`. Where very shortly it can become unwieldy with 4 or 5 flags columns. Instead normalizing to separate tables with the corresponding relationships helps keep entities organized and light.

Comment: I just ran into such case. I have a ``users`` table and a ``user_types`` table, but only a certain user_type should also have a relationship to ``homes`` table. Where would that relationship go? I don't want a ``home_id`` column in my ``users`` table. Do I create a pivot table for this then?

Comment: @Vic - This is really up to your design sense.  Having only one predicate (column) - i.e. `home_id` on a table in addition to the primary key (presumably `user_id`) is a pretty edge case for using a sub-type table.  If you find it really objectionable to have a nullable foreign key to your home table on your user table then this is really your only alternative.